# Open a lightning app in a new browser tab

Tags: lightning-apps

I have been developing two different lightning app in a Sandbox. What I want to do is to access from one app to the other one.

Specifically, I would like to show a button in one of the apps, and when I push it, a new browser tab (not a webtab from salesforce, I mean a new Chrome tab) will be opened with the other lightning app.

I have been doing some research, and I read that calling an URL like 'https://na24.lightning.force.com/c/MyLightningApp.app' would be enough, but according to last releases documentation (Spring 18 I think), these URLs are no longer available, so, do you know any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that in my Summer '18 pre-release org, `/c/AppName.app` still works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about that. Consider this excerpt from Summer 18 release notes.

> Existing URLs that use /one/one.app, like ones you’ve saved or have in
>   emails, will continue to work. When they’re executed, they’re
>   translated into the new format

Only precaution is to be cautious using window.location or the aura:locationChange as they are URL sensetive.

You can read more about it here:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_general_new_url_format_lex.htm